# Will bootable usb created by bootcamp on mac work with PC?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, usb, bootable-disk

I need to make a bootable usb with windows 8 files on it, I can't think of easier option than creating it via help of bootcamp, but Will it work for pc (I want to install files on my pc)?

Comment: Bootcamp won't do what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reading through several stackexchange answers, I found steps that worked on [this site](http://www.pyrosoft.co.uk/blog/2013/01/09/creating-a-bootable-usb-stick-from-osx/).

He walks you through how to format the USB stick so that Windows will recognize it, and how to use Unetbootin to copy the ISO image.

I'll reproduce the steps here for convenience:

## Format the disk in Disk Utility, with the correct MBR

1. Open Disk Utilty
2. Select the USB device
3. Click Partition
4. Select 1 partition in the partition layout
5. Select “Master Boot Record” in the options
6. Select MS-DOS (FAT) in the format type.
7. Click Apply, then Partition
8. Close Disk Utility

This will wipe the USB disk and set it up with the correct boot record

## Install the MBR binary from the SysLinux project

1. Use the command line diskutil to find the device name for your USB drive.

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```
2. Unmount the USB drive with the command line. NB: Be sure to swap the device reference (in my case it is /dev/SOMEdisk2) with the correct one for your usb key that you identified in the previous step – this will change for each machine.

   ```
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/SOMEdisk2
   ```
3. Mark the partition active, then unmount it again

   ```
   sudo fdisk -e /dev/SOMEdisk2
   print
   f 1
   write
   print
   exit
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/SOMEdisk2
   ```
4. [Download Syslinux](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-5.00.zip) and extract the mbr.bin file
5. Install the MBR

   ```
   sudo dd conv=notrunc bs=440 count=1 if=mbr.bin of=/dev/SOMEdisk2
   ```

   NB: see my full instructions if you need further help with steps 4 & 5.

## Use UnetBootin to install your OS install files

1. Download and install UnetBootin if you haven’t already
2. Load the application, choose your preferred distribution, and then click OK
3. When it’s finished, eject the USB key and use it

Comment: Find the most recent Syslinux .zip at https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/ (versions after 5 don't seem to have the mbr.bin file used in the above dd command).

Comment: UNebootin (613) just doesn't respond when I choose a distro or .iso and click OK with the USB drive formated this way (used Syslinux 5.10 mbr.bin) :T

Comment: Chiming in to say thanks - this worked like a charm after originally getting "this version of bootcamp is not intended" errors after having installed the Bootcamp-created USB-based Windows 10 on my new PC.

Comment: Followed it closely, got "Non-system disk" on boot. Using windows 10 64

Comment: Not able to boot. Automatic boot run time in loop mode..

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that, and all i get is a black screen and a white blinking underscore. I have tried other things to fix but I can't seem to fine a good enough solution. Also, my pc is brand new and I built so there is no optical drive. Plus, i have never installed windows before.

Comment: Did you make a bootable USB drive using bootcamp? Just adding the outline of the steps you took might help others know wha not to do and just maybe someone could point out a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

No. Bootcamp will make a bootable copy of Windows for a Mac only. Macs have UEFI instead of traditional BIOSes. PCs are adopting this technology but slowly.

I believe OS X formats the USB stick using GUID/HFS+, which PCs and Windows do not like. There are just too many hurdles to believe a bootable copy of Windows will work on a PC.

However, you could try this alternative method: [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x)

Note: Just make sure the USB stick is formatted using MBR instead of GUID to maximize impartiality.

Comment: @ekaj How do you figure that? He says with the help of Bootcamp. Moreover, read the actual title of his question. To me that reads that he is trying to use the option within Bootcamp to create the bootable USB installer. Also, please don't use the vote system out of angst. Please conduct yourself with maturity.

Comment: I down voted your answer because it wasn't one. You basically said "yeah maybe." You also didn't answer the question correctly as there is more evidence to suggest that he wanted to use a bootcamp created USB installer than using bootcamp to install Windows and then make the USB installer from that environment. You also didn't provide any detail (clear steps, potential caveats, etc.). We here aim for quality answers, not quick remarks. If anything, your reply would have best been served as a comment.

Comment: Indeed. Hence my comment above.

Comment: Just tested - Boot Camp creates an MBR-formatted drive

Answer (score 1):

When I used the Bootcamp Assistant to create a bootable USB from my Windows 8 ISO  my PC just hung on a flashing cursor in text mode while the activity light on my USB key blinked.

I believe the Apple Bootcamp installer prepares the USB key for EFI boot only (because that's what Mac's need) and does not properly prepare MBR boot code.  My motherboard (ASRock H77-PRO4-M) fully supports EFI, but defaults to trying MBR boot.  I had to explicitly choose the UEFI boot option form my boot menu (F11 or F12 at power on) and with that the installer booted perfectly:

[image: BIOS Boot Selector: Choose USB UEFI]

Answer (score 1):

You can boot a drive that doesn't contain BootCamp Helper from a Mac, but you can't boot a drive that does contain BootCamp Helper from a PC.

Installing BootCamp Helper on a External Drive for both PC and Mac is just like installing it on a Mac. Have a look at this [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3866645) where the OP has installed BootCamp Helper on a regular PC for more information.

> Apple "Boot Camp" is the motherboard chip support. PCs don't have a Mac logicboard. Windows does not like having mobo drivers that don't belong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the methods listed in this thread to create a Windows 7 bootable USB and none worked for me. What ended working was:

1. Follow the steps in Boot Camp to create the bootable USB.
2. Install [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/ca/) on my mac loading Windows from the USB I created in step 1.
3. In Parallels, download and install [Windows USB/DVD download tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/)
4. Use Windows USB/DVD download tool in Parallels to create the new properly formatted bootable USB.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm running macOS Sierra using version 6.1.0 of Boot Camp Assistant. I was able to create a bootable USB drive from a Windows 10 .iso file by selecting the "Create a Windows 7 or later version install disk," after first formatting the drive using Disk Utility to DOS_FAT_32 filesystem and MBR partition.

When I plugged the drive into my newly built PC, I was able to successfully boot from the USB drive and install Windows 10. After installation was completed, a notice did pop up saying that my machine wasn't compatible with Boot Camp, so I assume that Boot Camp Assistant included some Mac-specific drivers and support libraries that aren't necessary on Windows. However, I don't think that should cause any issues, and I was able to produce a bootable USB drive using Boot Camp Assistant.

The answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123876/221151) also seems to indicate that this should be possible.